# Using named pipe to communicate between unicode and non-unicode processes on windows

Tags: winapi, unicode, named-pipes

If a process with unicode enabled creates a named pipe, it must pass a LPCTSTR for the pipe name, in this case a LPCWSTR. Will a second process wihtout unicode be able to open that pipe by passing a LPCSTR for the pipe name?

Also, can I call CreateNamedPipeW or CreateNamedPipeA and ignore whether unicode is enabled, or do I have to call the appropriate one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes aren't Unicode or non-Unicode, they're just processes. The Unicode/non-Unicode distinction applies only to windows and window-related objects.

You can call either of the two functions. The A version merely converts the string to UTF-16 and passes it to the W function.

Comment: Thanks, I think that clears it up. By unicode- or non-unicode-process I mean a program that was compiled with UNICODE defined or not.